# how to insert values of a form in global variables

Tags: javascript

In this example the first console.log() works because it's into a function but the second doesn't

```js
function onload() {
  lolz = document.getElementById('lolz');
  lolz2 = document.getElementById('lolz2');
  lolz3 = document.getElementById('lolz3');
}
var v;

function kk() {
  onload();
  v = lolz.value;
  return v;
  console.log(v);
}
console.log(kk());
```

```html
<body onload="onload();">
  <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz" />
  <input type="text" name="enter2" class="enter" value="" id="lolz2" />
  <input type="text" name="enter3" class="enter" value="" id="lolz3" />
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();" />
</body>
```

Comment: You need to return the value from the function `kk`. If you don't explicitly return any value `undefined` is returned. Are you looking for returning the value `v` from the function ?

Comment: *In this example the first console.log() works because it's into a function but the second doesn't* Huh? What do you mean? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to display the content of the variable v outside of the function kk()

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value within `kk` function

```js
function onload() {
  lolz = document.getElementById('lolz');
  lolz2 = document.getElementById('lolz2');
  lolz3 = document.getElementById('lolz3');
}
var v;

function kk() {
  onload();
  
  v = lolz ? lolz.value : false;
  console.log(v);
  return v;
}
console.log(kk());
```

```html
<body onload="onload();">
  <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz" />
  <input type="text" name="enter2" class="enter" value="" id="lolz2" />
  <input type="text" name="enter3" class="enter" value="" id="lolz3" />
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();" />
</body>
```

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work.
the console return : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at kk

Comment: I've updated the snippet , the input is not present on DOM when the code is executed . ( For this case will be displayed false )

Comment: better but it doesn't display kk()

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to

```
function kk() {
  onload();
  v = lolz.value;
  console.log("first : "+v);
}
console.log("second : "+kk());
```

and run it, you will see both are executed.